# If all the factors of two polynomials are the same, are they equivalent in the associated sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{q^\alpha}$ be an integer ring of modulo $q^\alpha$. Let $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_{q^\alpha}[x]$, where $q$ is a prime number. If polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ have the same set of factors,  are they equivalent in the associated sense?

Comment: In $Z_{27}[x]$, the polynomals $3x$ and $9x$ are not associated.

Comment: You might mean the finite field of $q^a$ elements instead, although the comment above still shows the statement isn’t quite true.

Comment: Sorry, what I want to ask is the relationship when $\mathbb{Z}_{q^\alpha}$ is a ring.

Comment: @worm: Doesn't my initial comment answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, the $9x$ should not be a factor of $3x$, so their sets of factors are not  the same. I want to know if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same set of factors, are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ unique in the associated sense?

Comment: What do you mean by associated sense? They will only differ by a constant multiple.

Comment: Associated sense means $\exists u(x)$ is a unit such that $f(x) = g(x) u(x)$.

Comment: Do you mean irreducible factors?

Comment: I mean  that all reducible and irreducible factors are the same.